# Number of distinct derivatives of order $n$ of an $m$-variable function

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, multivariable-calculus, combinatorial-proofs

*Advanced Calculus* 2nd ed., by David Widder, says that the number of distinct (partial) derivatives of order $n$ of a (presumably smooth) function of $m$ variables is given by

$$\binom{n+m-1}{n} = \frac{(n+m-1)!}{n! (m-1)!}.$$

I drew out a tree diagram with the root being the original function $f$, and whose children as $f_{1}, \cdots, f_{m}$ representing the first partial derivatives of $f$ wrt to each input. Each of these, $f_i$ have children as well, given by $f_{i,1}, \cdots, f_{i,m}$. And these have children as well, etc.

This tree-like diagram gave me an enjoyable visual that suggests for a given order we must count the number of leaves of an $m$-furcating tree of depth $n$ from the root.

I have tried to think about the addition and product rules of counting with little success. How do I derive this counting equation?

Comment: This takes into account the equality of mixed partials, $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ for sufficiently Smooth functions. So for example there are three different second partial derivatives for a function of two variables: $f_{xx}$
, $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yy}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y_i$ be the number of times the derivative is taken with respect to $x_i$.  You want to count the nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^m y_i = n$. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the count is $\binom{n+m-1}{n}$.